# Fixing a flat tire

Tags: phrase-request

I got a flat tire, I want to have it fixed.
Is there any particular way to say *having your car's flat tire repaired* ? Or that (for example : *" I'm going to have the car's flat tire repaired"*) is just fine?

Comment: You can fix your car, either by repairing the flat tire, or replacing the flat tire (or eventually both front/rear tires). "I'm having/gonna have my flat tire repaired/replaced" is fine, unless you're the one fixing it, in which case it's "I'm repairing/replacing (or going to repair/replace) my car's flat tire".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your car, either by repairing the flat tire, or replacing the flat tire (or eventually both front/rear tires). 
**"I'm having/going to have my flat tire repaired/replaced"** is fine, unless you're the one fixing it, in which case it's **"I'm repairing/replacing (or going to repair/replace) my car's flat tire"**.